# flash app converted to native iphone/android/windows phone?

Tags: android, iphone, flash, windows-mobile, audio-streaming

I need some advice please, I once made an app for iphone with flash builder. I didn't submit it to apple but got it on an iphone. I was wondering if this is something that can be done as I don't want to re learn xcode, and have zero interest in android and windows mobile...

I have client that wants me to build a radio streaming app (the same app on three platforms).

also wondering if i should use node.js for the backend as i can already connect flash or use something like this http://www.streamsolution.net/it/streaming/audio/ ?

I also would be fine with js in the app if that is viable? what do you think i my best solution?

On one hand I am worried about load balancing lots of listeners on node.js and on the other I'm not sure about these phones and how the deal with both flash apps and streaming?

Wize words?

Comment: then might be less chance for it..

Comment: flash app converted to native iphone/android/windows  if you nt learn xcode or android or ios then 1 chance for use titanium or phonegap pluggin for that

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying